# Django Channels using django shell

Tags: python, django, django-celery, django-channels

I'm currently am trying to use Celery to send sockets with django channels. However I found the same issue there as with using Django's shell, and was hoping if someone could enlighten me.

I have it set up so that within views.py, when a user sends a POST request it will call

```
Group("chat").send({'text':'hello'})
```

The browser then displays an alert.

However when I try to do the same thing using Django's shell or one of Celery's tasks:

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
$ from channels import Group
$ Group("chat").send({'text': 'hello'})
```

It doesn't do anything, not even returning an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `In-Memory` Channel Layer then likely `it does not support cross-process communication.` So try with other channel layer types and you are good to go.